# Symfony bundle configuration array node default value merge

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, bundle, symfony4

I have a problem with Symfony4 bundle configuration. I have a configuration class with:

```
$rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('mapping')
                ->useAttributeAsKey('code')
                ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                ->defaultValue(['default' => 'test'])
            ->end()
            .....
        ->end();
```

This returns a default configuration like:

```
array(1) {
   ["default"]=> string(4) "test"
}
```

But when I add a configuration file:

```
bundle:
    mapping:
        test: newvalue
        test2: newvalue2
```

Im getting a config:

```
array(2) {
   ["test"]=> string(8) "newvalue"
   ["test2"]=> string(9) "newvalue2"
}
```

But I expect to merge these two configs to get:

```
array(3) {
   ["default"]=> string(4) "test"
   ["test"]=> string(8) "newvalue"
   ["test2"]=> string(9) "newvalue2"
}
```

How can I set this defaults to be merged with provided configurations? Of course I want to let "default" config to be overridden, but by deafult to be merged.

I cant find any solution on docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-node-options

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the `default` entry to be always defined. Applicaions will be able to overwrite the default value `DEFAULT` of `default` key.

Ok, there are two solutions :

**A bad solution**

```
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('mapping')
                ->useAttributeAsKey('code')
                ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                ->beforeNormalization()
                    ->ifArray()
                    ->then(function ($mapping) {
                        return $mapping + ['default' => 'DEFAULT'];
                    })
                ->end()
            ->end();
```

If default key is not defined it will be added along with default `DEFAULT` value. It will function for **ONE** configuration file parsed. BUT you will get the problem if you have two and more configuraion files:

```
# config.yml
mapping:
    some: value
    default: MY_DEVELOPMENT_DEFAULT

# prod/config.yml
mapping:
    some: value_prod
```

You will have :

```
['some' => 'value_prod', 'default' => 'DEFAULT']
```

This is wrong. Default value replaces `MY_DEVELOPMENT_DEFAULT` because it was added to `prod/config.yml` and merged with `config.yml`.

Unfortunately, tree builder doesn't permit to define callback after merge.

**A good solution**

You can add your default entries after the configuraion values are merged (e.g. in compiler passes).

Answer (score 6):

For this you have to define the Array Configuration deeper:

```
$treeBuilder
   ->children()
       ->arrayNode('mapping')
           ->ignoreExtraKeys()
           ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
           ->children()
               ->scalarNode('default')
                   ->defaultValue('test)
               ->end()
           ->end()
       ->end()
   ->end()
```

The addDefaultsIfNotSet will add your default values.
The ignoreExtraKeys lets you define additional keys like in your example.
It would be better to fully configure the keys, because you have better control over them.